# HTML button not clickable with flex class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I am pretty new to HTML.
I am unable to work with a button onClick.
When I add this flex to mt submit button it becomes non-clickable (i.e. onClick doesn't trigger)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('loaded');
  console.log(document.getElementById("submitbutton"));
  document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  })
}
```

```css
/*--contct button--*/

.contact-form .single-contact-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background: #b636ff;
  border: 1px solid #b636ff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-form .single-contact-btn .contact-btn,
.contact-form .single-contact-btn .contact-btn:focus {
  margin-top: 0px;
  outline: 0 !important;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.single-contact-btn:hover {
  background: #9f00ff;
  border: 1px solid #9f00ff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="single-contact-btn">
    <button class="contact-btn" id="submitbutton" type="button">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, if I remove the "single-contact-btn" class, button onclick starts working.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div>
        <button class="contact-btn" id="submitbutton"
            type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with the "single-contact-btn" class that is messing with the button?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the element you see really is `#submitbutton`.

Comment: It seems to be working for me as long as I click on the button itself, not the purple area behind it.

Comment: Agreed with @lineal here

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is, also with `single-contact-btn` class attached to the div.  If your expectations are not wrong (see lineal's comment above), and you've linked a bootstrap script to the page, it's possible, that the button is replaced with another element that has not the specified id.

Comment: yessss @lineal, thank you so much, that's a silly,  now I just made add ```button {
    padding: 1.3rem 3.7rem;
    width: auto;
}``` to let the button fully take the flex and added a transition color to it

Answer (score 1):

You've added an event to the element with `getElementById("submitbutton")`. This means when you click the area of this specific element, the associated event will execute. If you want to execute an event on all elements with the class 'single-contact-btn', you would use the getElementsByClassName() method. To target a specific element within that class, you can add a unique ID to that element and then use getElementById().

Here's an example:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="single-contact-btn" id="submitbutton">
    <button class="contact-btn" type="button">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @lineal pointed the error I was doing, my button was not stretched across the whole flex, This is one working solution also, thanks for pointing out the area-button difference